# Pad block corrupted for bouncycastle library and Modal dialog cannot be displayed on a minimized app

Tags: codenameone

I have following questions for CN1

1. I'm not sure this is because of CN1 or Bouncy Castle itself. I started seeing this error recently on the device. I'm not able to reproduce this issue in simulator.

   ```
   [EDT] 0:0:0,4 - Exception: java.io.IOException - org.bouncycastle.crypto.InvalidCipherTextException: pad block corrupted
          java.io.IOException
       at com_codename1_crypto_EncryptedStorage.createInputStream:70
       at com_codename1_io_Storage.readObject:263
       at com_codename1_io_Preferences.get:84
       at com_codename1_io_Preferences.get:252
       at c_server_ServerImpl.__INIT__:49
       at _server_Server.__CLINIT__:14
       at _Main.init:51
       at _MainStub.run:30
       at com_codename1_ui_Display.processSerialCalls:1298
       at com_codename1_ui_Display.mainEDTLoop:1093
   ```
2. I started seeing this message also recently on iOS.

   > Modal dialog cannot be displayed on a minimized app.

I don't display no dialog except using infinite container.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the modal dialog is due to the exception being caught by the EDT main thread. It shows an error dialog normally.

A file you're trying to read in the encrypted storage was corrupted. Probably written to before the encryption took place. It looks like something was saved to preferences before the encryption was enacted in this case. I would suggest calling `setPreferencesLocation` to set a different file name immediately after applying encryption to avoid such a situation.